# htaccess - File directory is being wrongly redirected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wrote an htaccess code to redirect calls from http://localhost/website/article.php?id=5 to http://localhost/website/article/5

My resources url is being renamed as well. Here is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule article/([0-9@.-])  article.php?id=$1
```

but now the resources is being redirected to non existent http://localhost/website/article/js/main.js instead of http://localhost/website/js/main.js

Comment: Thanks!  Save me a lot of time